# Trying to understand why an enhanced for loop will not work for adding key value pairs to an object

Tags: javascript

Trying to understand why the enhanced for loop will not add the key value pairs to the object. I know I can do this with a regular for loop, but why does the enhanced for loop not work? Is it a syntax error?

```
  function transformArrayToObject(array) {
  // your code here
  var obj = {};
  
  // Loop through array of arrays adding the first and last as key value pairs
  for (var arrayOfArray in array) {
    obj[[arrayOfArray][0]] = arrayOfArray[1];
  }

  return obj;
}
var input = [['make', 'Ford'], ['model', 'Mustang'], ['year', 1964]];

var result = transformArrayToObject(input);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Use `of` not `in`. You could also do `array.reduce((a, [k, v]) => {a[k] = v; return a}, {})`.

Comment: Never mind I see that you cannot use in for an Array thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: `[arrayOfArray][0] === arrayOfArray`, since it's the 0th element of the array [arrayOfArray]

Answer (score 1):

In line 7, you maybe meant to write `obj[array[arrayOfArray][0]] = array[arrayOfArray][1];` instead.
`for x in y` will give you the indexes x of y.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making this a `for of` rather than `for in` loop, this line had the error:

```
obj[arrayOfArray[0]] = arrayOfArray[1];
```

You were creating a new array as the new key with `obj[[arrayOfArray[0]]] = arrayOfArray[1];`

```js
function transformArrayToObject(array) {
  // your code here
  var obj = {};

  // Loop through array of arrays adding the first and last as key value pairs
  for (var arrayOfArray of array) {
    obj[arrayOfArray[0]] = arrayOfArray[1];
  }

  return obj;
}
var input = [
  ['make', 'Ford'],
  ['model', 'Mustang'],
  ['year', 1964]
];

var result = transformArrayToObject(input);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you're trying to achieve:

```
function transformArrayToObject(array) {
    // your code here
    var obj = {};
    
    // Loop through array of arrays adding the first and last as key value pairs
    for (var arrayOfArray in array) {
      obj[array[arrayOfArray][0]] = array[arrayOfArray][1];
    }
  
    return obj;
  }
  var input = [['make', 'Ford'], ['model', 'Mustang'], ['year', 1964]];
  
  var result = transformArrayToObject(input);
  console.log(result);
```

`in` keyword is different in python and javascript. Javascript makes it provide the index. You can do the same with `of`, and it looks a bit cleaner:

```
function transformArrayToObject(array) {
    // your code here
    var obj = {};
    
    // Loop through array of arrays adding the first and last as key value pairs
    for (var arrayOfArray of array) {
      obj[arrayOfArray[0]] = arrayOfArray[1]
    }
  
    return obj;
  }
  var input = [['make', 'Ford'], ['model', 'Mustang'], ['year', 1964]];
  
  var result = transformArrayToObject(input);
  console.log(result);
```